# Node js Infinitive loop (setTimeout or setInterval)

Tags: node.js, callback, request, dnode

Hi have some code dnode function with callback:

```
    const dnode = require('dnode');
    const request = require('request');
    const daemon = dnode.connect(45848); 

    function requestInfo() {
            daemon.on('remote', (rpc) => {
                rpc.status(callback);
            });
            var callback = (err, infos) => {
                ...........
                request.post({
                    .........
                });
            }
        }
```

when i request it once just when script executed all is ok. Info send and requesting, but when i use for example `setTimeout(requestInfo, 10000);` or interval the script is stuck and don't execute even 1 time.

I need to `rpc.status(callback);` every minute

Comment: When you pass in the function `requestInfo` to `setTimeout()`, is the variable `daemon` still referring to the object you want it to refer to when the function is ran?
`daemon` might have not been declared in your `setTimeout`'s callback function (`requestInfo`) unless you you used `.bind()` on the callback being passed into `setTimeout`

Comment: Deamon is dnode connect . Add full script. May you add example. Node js isn't may strong side:)

Comment: Can you also show where you are calling `setTimeout`?